# Chrome extension to listen and capture streaming audio

Tags: google-chrome, audio, google-chrome-extension, audio-streaming, audio-capture

Is it possible for a Chrome extension to listen for streaming audio from any of the browser's tabs?  I would like to capture the streaming audio data and then analyse it.

Thanks

Comment: Off the top of my head (and initial googling backs this up), I can't find any way to do this. It also sounds like a massive security hole, so I can't imagine any browser would be in a hurry to support it.

Comment: Do you have to listen for audio?  Can you watch for network requests instead?  Is this to work on any site, or for one particular site?  Are you targeting all platforms, or just one?

Comment: Well i would like to grab the streaming audio data(say from an online radio show) and send it to an audio fingerprinting service. Ideally it would work on any site and I'll probably start out with targeting just Chrome.

Comment: If the streaming audio is coming with an Audio Object, and is not inside an iframe, you cant "grab" it with AudioContext object and manipulate the stream for instance.
Something like 
http://lab.ejci.net/Chrome-Audio-EQ/#

Comment: Yes. It's possible. Please review this answer of mine.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945755/chrome-extension-capture-tab-audio/78155918#78155918

Answer (score 11):

You could try 3 ways, neither one does provide 100% guarantee to meet your needs.

Before going into more detailed descriptions, I must note that Chrome extensions do not provide convenient tools for working on per connection level - sufficiently *low level*, required for stream capturing. This is by design. This is why the 1-st way is:

1. To look at other browsers, for example Firefox, which provides low-level APIs for connections. They are already known to be used by similar extensions. You may have a look at [MediaStealer](http://code.google.com/p/mediastealer/). If you do not have a specific requirement to build your system on Chrome, you should possibly move to Firefox.
2. You can develop a Chrome extension, which intercepts HTTP-requests by means of [webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onHeadersReceived) API, analyses their headers and extracts media urls (such as containing audio/mpeg MIME-type, for example, in HTTP-headers). Just for a quick example of code you make look at the following SO question - [How to change response header in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13700394/1102014). Having the url you may force appropriate media download as a file. It will land in default downloads folder and may have unfriendly name. (I made such an extension, but I do not have requirements for further processing). If you need to further process such files, it can be a challenge to monitor them in the folder, and run additional analysis in a separate program.
3. You may have a look at NPAPI plugins in general, and their [streaming APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference/Streams#Receiving_a_Stream) in particular. I can imagine that you create a plugin registered for, again, audio/mpeg MIME-type, and receives the data via `NPP_NewStream`, `NPP_WriteReady` and `NPP_Write` methods. The plugin can be wrapped into a Chrome extension. Though I made NPAPI plugins, I never used this API, and I'm not sure it will work as expected. Nethertheless, I'm mentioning this possibility here for completenees. This method requires some coding other than web-coding, meaning C/C++. *NB. NPAPI plugins are deprecated and not supported in Chrome since September 2015.*

Taking into account that you have some external (to the extension) "fingerprinting service" in mind, which sounds like an intelligent data processing, you may be interested in building all the system out of a browser. For example, you could, possibly, involve a HTTP-proxy, saving media from passing traffic.

Answer (score 8):

If you're writing a Chrome extension, you can use the [Chrome tabCapture API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture) to record audio.

```
chrome.tabCapture.capture({audio: true}, function(stream) {
  var recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  [...]
});
```

The rest is left as an exercise to the reader; MDN has [more documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API) on how to use MediaRecorder.

When this question was asked in 2013, neither chrome.tabCapture nor MediaRecorder existed.

Answer (score 3):

Mac OSX solution using soundflower: http://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/

After installing soundflower it should appear as a separate audio device in the sound preferences (apple > system preferences > sound). Divert the computer's audio to the 2ch option (stereo, 16ch is surround), then inside a DAW, such as 'audacity', set the audio input as soundflower. Now the sound should be channeled to your DAW ready for recording.

Note: having diverted the audio from the internal speakers to soundflower you will only be able to hear the audio if the 'soundflowerbed' app is actually open. You know it's open if there's a 8 legged blob in the top right task bar. Clicking this icon gives you the sound flower options.

Answer (score 1):

My privoxy has the following log:

```
2013-08-28 18:25:27.953 00002f44 Request: api.audioaddict.com/v1/di/listener_sessions.jsonp?_method=POST&callback=_AudioAddict_WP_ListenerSession_create&listener_session%5Bid%5D=null&listener_session%5Bis_premium%5D=false&listener_session%5Bmember_id%5D=null&listener_session%5Bdevice_id%5D=6&listener_session%5Bchannel_id%5D=178&listener_session%5Bstream_set_key%5D=webplayer&_=1377699927926
2013-08-28 18:25:27.969 0000268c Request: api.audioaddict.com/v1/ping.jsonp?callback=_AudioAddict_WP_Ping__ping&_=1377699927928
2013-08-28 18:25:27.985 00002d48 Request: api.audioaddict.com/v1/di/track_history/channel/178.jsonp?callback=_AudioAddict_TrackHistory_Channel&_=1377699927942
2013-08-28 18:25:54.080 00003360 Request: pub7.di.fm/di_progressivepsy_aac?type=.flv
```

So I got the stream url and record it:

```
D:\Profiles\user\temp>wget pub7.di.fm/di_progressivepsy_aac?type=.flv
--18:26:32--  http://pub7.di.fm/di_progressivepsy_aac?type=.flv
           => `di_progressivepsy_aac@type=.flv'
Resolving pub7.di.fm... done.
Connecting to pub7.di.fm[67.221.255.50]:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [video/x-flv]

    [                   <=>               ] 1,234,151      8.96K/s
```

I got the file that can be reproduced in any multimedia pleer.