# Chrome Extension - capture / stream sound

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, google-chrome-extension

I am (very) new to the whole Chrome Extension building and I am curious if it is possible to create an Extension which, on first click, starts "recording" the current tab's audio stream, and on second click, stops it and makes the resulting data available (in any format which might then be downloaded)

I did my Google searches but can't find any relevant code examples from which I could start... the documentation seems to be very, very sparse.
I am basically just asking a similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945755/chrome-extension-capture-tab-audio) however, maybe making it a wee bit more specific.

Any help of any sort would be great!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll probably want to wait until MediaStreamRecorder is launched. crbug.com/262211