# Chrome, cache everything except one file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to tell Chrome to cache everything except one file (is there some kind of extension for it)?

It could be useful during development if I'm changing only one js file and I don't want to re-download entire app, I just want this new JS.

Comment: Why not use _proper_ mechanisms by making the server pass no-cache directives for that file?

Comment: It could be an idea, but I'm currently working on frontend part only and I really don't know how to set up my server to do that.

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer right now, but I think [`webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) can be used quite easily to insert / override response headers that regulate caching.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out! I'll post here with my findings

Comment: @Xan Caching behavior cannot be controlled through the webRequest API, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17382259 and https://crbug.com/355232.

Comment: @SlavenTomac See my previous comment before you waste time on chasing a dead end.

Comment: Ok guys, thank you all for your comments here...I guess I'll have to jump on server and try to add no-cache to this file...

Comment: You simply modify the js right on the chrome debugger. No need to reload the app.

Answer (score 0):

The chrome debugger lets you change a js file on the fly. Just change the code and save it within the chrome debugger so you can test the new code without reloading the app or page.

Comment: Yes, for some things like a directive you would need to re-parse the file. I dont think angular allows for that.

Comment: Make the app so it works locally loaded from a local directory so reloading is fast.