# Cache http responses with no-cache header in Electron

Tags: caching, electron

I'm trying to wrap an existing web app in an Electron app in order to improve the performance.

I would like to override the cache strategy for certain web service calls as I know it will improve performance based on the way I use the website.

I don't control the web app so I cannot make any changes to that.

I have wrapped the web app in a `BrowserView`.
Some of the endpoints that the web app using have have this response header: `cache-control: no-cache, no-store, no-transform`.

I would like to cache the result for 1 minute even though the server tell me not to.

So far I have tried to override the response header like this:

```js
session.defaultSession.webRequest.onHeadersReceived((details, callback) => {
  let headers = details.responseHeaders

  headers["Cache-Control"] = ["max-age=60"]

  return callback({responseHeaders: headers})
})
```

But Electron is ignoring the updated response header entirely.

Any ideas to how I can force another caching strategy than the server suggests?

Comment: This may not be possible, in chrome you can't do something like this and since electron is at the end of the day just a chromium implementation, I don't think it is possible either. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17382259/10213537

Comment: Thanks for the comment   I guess I can compile and use my own Chromium with support for cache override - that seems like the last option I should try to explore though :)