# Can a chrome extension change the page charset?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new to chrome extension development. I want to use extension to change page charset, like chrome setting>>tools>>charset. And I had seen the document with chrome extension about chrome.contentSetting[1](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings.html#type-ContentSetting). but I had not found how to change page charset.

Comment: Is your extension released?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Via [how to change response header in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700394/how-to-change-response-header-in-chrome):

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details){
    for(var i = 0; i < details.responseHeaders.length; ++i)
        if(details.responseHeaders[i].name.toLowerCase() == 'content-type')
            details.responseHeaders[i].value = 'text/html; charset=shift-jis';
    return {responseHeaders:details.responseHeaders};
}, {urls: ['https://www.google.com/*']}, ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']);
```

If you want to update the charset on pageload, you will need a `chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener` that updates meta tags in the document `<head>`. This cannot be a called pragmatically via `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` as the document is rendered with the specified charset.

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(details){
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {allFrames:true,code:"document.getElementsByTagName('meta')[0].setAttribute('content', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8');"});
    });
}, {urls: ['http://google.com/']});
```

Either of these functions go in your `background.js` file that is loaded in `manifest.json`:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    // name,description,version...
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": true,
        //"matches": ["https://google.com/"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ]
}
```

Once a page is initialized and rendered, there is no way to change the charset. `document.charset` is readonly, and triggering a re-render does not appear to affect the document charset, even if altered.

Comment: This is a solution to change it _before_ the page loads; question is still open for an already-loaded page.

Comment: So I guess the best approximation to a post-load change is "Activate webRequest listener, reload, deactivate listener".

Comment: That would work - actually a great idea for a standalone extension.

Comment: Yeah, except that one can never assume that reloading a URL does not have side-effects. Users must be aware of it.