# How to replace/set response headers (Chrome extensions)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, http-headers

I'm trying to change chrome headers. I've tried two approaches

```
1) use chrome extensions
2) Write my own extension
```

1) I've installed [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa) and added a rule

[image]

Now if I load, for example, facebook.com and open the dev-tools, I don't see this response header

[image]

I don't see why this doesn't work. I assume that the rule set in Requestly applies to all tabs.

2) This approach was inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700394/how-to-change-response-header-in-chrome) post. So, I created an extensions with the following code:

```
function updateHeaders() {
    chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details){
        for(var i = 0; i < details.responseHeaders.length; ++i)
            if(details.responseHeaders[i].name.toLowerCase() == 'server')
                details.responseHeaders[i].value = 'barfoo';
        return {responseHeaders:details.responseHeaders};
    }, {urls: ['*://*']}, ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', updateHeaders());
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Getting started example",
    "description": "Replace the server header",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Click here!"
   },
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest"
    ]
}
```

Which doesn't work too

I must admit I have no experience with building chrome extensions, so the changes are pretty big that what I'm trying here doesn't make any sense, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Youve set your filter to request, not response...

Comment: check, thats a mistake I made for this screen shot! Anyway, even with `response` set I noticed that `Add` sometimes works but `Modify` doesn't. I'm also not sure what to do to have changes take effect; do I have to kill the browser. I didn't discover a pattern yet.

Comment: Id imagine its whether its pulling data from cache or not

Comment: Even in that case I can imagine that the extension is in the middle and does its magic

Comment: Dunno, because in effect it already has it cached it, i can see it would feed you what it has from before.

Comment: Adding `--disable-web-security --user-data-dir` to chrome seems to fix this

Comment: Requestly Developer here, Please have a look at this: https://github.com/requestly/chrome-extension/issues/127. It simply proves the point about modification in response headers do work but are not visible in Developer tools.